# Invalid prop of type `string` in react

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

In my MuiTable I have:

```
        <MuiTable
        padding="dense"
        data={pageData}
                    pagination={{ 
                        count: data ? data.length : 0,
                        rowsPerPage: count,
                            page: page - 1,
                            rowsPerPageOptions: [10, 25, 100, 500],
                            onChangePage: this.handlePageChange,
                            onChangeRowsPerPage: this.handleCountChange, 
                        }}
```

and

```
const mapStateToProps = (state , props) => {
const search: any = deparamSearch(props.location.search);

return {
    orders: (state.orders.list || []),
    page: Number.parseInt(search.page || 1),
    count: search.count || 10,
};
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
    fetchOrders: (values, search?) => dispatch(fetchOrders(values, search)),
});
```

and getting the warning:

```
Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `rowsPerPage` of type `string` supplied to `TablePaginationActions`, expected `number`
```

looks like count is a string while I'm doing these calculations with no errors:

```
const data = orders;
const start = count * (page - 1);
const pageData = data && data.slice(start, start + count);
```

and in my backend file:

```
public abstract Optional<Integer> count();
public abstract Optional<Integer> page();
```

I can't understand the reason `count` is a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, count is coming from this line:

`const search: any = deparamSearch(props.location.search);`

props.location.search is most likely to be a string. You need to set it to a Number, like:

`count: Number(search.count) || 10`

Also, you can do `'5' * 3` and that will return 15. That's because javascript try to cast the string `'5'` to a number because of the operator `*`

Answer (score -1):

Something is wrong with your database. You might have data as string, you may confirm it to be number:

```
rowsPerPage: +count // +'3' ==> 3
```

Sidenote: In react, if prop type is number, then it must be number but not the number in string format like '34' is invalid.